# Getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
df
    len  scores
    5      [0.45814112124905954, 0.34974337172257086, 0.042586941883761324, 0.042586941883761324, 0.33509446692807404, 0.01202741856859997, 0.01202741856859997, 0.031149023579740857, 0.031149023579740857, 0.9382029832667171]
    4      [0.1289882974831455, 0.17069367229950574, 0.03518847270370917, 0.3283517918439753, 0.41119171582425107, 0.5057528742869354]
    
    3      [0.22345885572316307, 0.1366147609256035, 0.09309687010700848]
    2      [0.4049920770888036]
```

I want to index the scores column based on len column value and get multiple rows

```
len    scores
5       [0.45814112124905954, 0.34974337172257086, 0.042586941883761324, 0.042586941883761324]
5       [0.33509446692807404, 0.01202741856859997, 0.01202741856859997]
5       [0.031149023579740857, 0.031149023579740857]
5       [0.9382029832667171]
5       
4       [0.1289882974831455, 0.17069367229950574, 0.03518847270370917]
4       [0.3283517918439753, 0.41119171582425107]
4       [0.9382029832667171]
4
3       [0.22345885572316307, 0.1366147609256035]
3       [0.09309687010700848]
3
2       [0.4049920770888036]
2
```

I tried the following code to get required results

```
def create_nested_list_s (x):
    l_idx = [0]+np.cumsum(np.arange(x['len'])[::-1]).tolist()
    return pd.Series([x['scores'][i:j] for i, j in zip(l_idx[:-1], l_idx[1:])])

df_f = (df.apply(create_nested_list_s, axis=1)
          .set_index(df['len'])
          .stack()
          .reset_index(name='scores')
          .drop('level_1', axis=1))
```

And I got the results in required format

```
len  scores
5      [0.45814112124905954, 0.34974337172257086, 0.042586941883761324, 0.042586941883761324]
4      [0.1289882974831455, 0.17069367229950574, 0.03518847270370917]
3      [0.22345885572316307, 0.1366147609256035]
2      [0.4049920770888036]
```

But the problem is I have multiple dataframes like 'len' and 'scores' columns but with different column names and want to use the same above function and get the data in above format.

I tried to add in dataframe column names itself as arguments and combine the two functions as follows:

```
def create_nested_list(x, col_len, col, col_name):
    l_idx = [0]+np.cumsum(np.arange(x[col_len])[::-1]).tolist()
    df =(x.apply(pd.Series([x[col][i:j] for i, j in zip(l_idx[:-1], l_idx[1:])]), axis=1)
        .set_index(x[col_len])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name=col_name)
        .drop('level_1', axis=1))
    return df
```

Assuming `df_test` is dataframe with `df_len` and `df_col` as different column names just like above df structure

```
testing = create_nested_list(df_test, 'df_len', 'df_col', 'df_name')
```

But I get ValueError:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any help to fix the function will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame.apply expects to get a function as its first parameter, which gets called once for each row.  You're not providing a function, you're providing a series.  You could try making it a lambda, but it's not clear you'd gain anything over the structure you originally had.